# How to reload classes storing database information at frequent intervals?

Tags: java, database, caching, cache-control

We have a WebApplication which at start-up fetches all required information from Database and stores it in Java maps.

These maps are later used throughout in the application to fetch information required.

But in this approach whatever updates are done in database are not reflected till you restart the application.

So how can we automatically reload such classes / repositories in Java?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What server? What kind of WebApp? You need asynchronous method or a thread to run in the background and do the fetching stuff for you. Should be easy.

Comment: You're loading your entire database to memory?

Comment: @pcalcao We are not loading the entire database but some information from it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I understood is that that you need to reload the classes only because you need to refresh the data, which was loaded from the DB during the start-up. Isn't that true? If yes, then if some other mechanism can get your data refreshed, then I don't think you would still need to reload your classes.

Try using some caching mechanism. Take a look at [EhCache](http://ehcache.org/).

You can go with Quartz scheduler, as others pointed out. But wait... that's also another library.

Well, you can also go by yourself using [Timer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Timer.html) and [TimerTask](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/TimerTask.html), otherwise. Just schedule that task for repeated execution, as you pointed out somewhere in the comments that you need to load it every hour.

Comment: I looked at some example videos on EhCache. And could see that the object is not put in cache if its already existing. So in my case even if object is existing there could be a change in one of its properties which make it a candidate for update. So is that update has to be handled by Hibernate like tool? And since we are using Redis I doubt if I can do that. What are your comments on this?

Comment: @Sam: You can force the cache to reload, based on some timely fashion, if you want.

Answer (score 0):

you can run some daemon `Thread` in background which actually intract with database in centain interval to update the latest data.

Also you can use standard cache mechanism for it like EhCache or Guava cache in order to achieve this.

Comment: The EhCache or Guava are cache management libraries? If yes, then how can they automatically reload the classes / repositories?

Comment: @AdeelAnsari I want to have actually a mechanism which will reload the classes after every hour. But I have not understood your view "Reloading the classes and repositories is not way we refresh/evict objects in/from the cache." . So do you mean EhCache should not be used?

Comment: Reloading the classes and repositories is not the way we refresh/evict objects in/from the cache. These are sophisticated APIs, with adequate configuration options. These usually works with different expiry, like element based or cache wide, and eviction, like LRU or LFU, policies.

Comment: Hey Sam, what I understood is that that you need to reload the classes only because you need to refresh the data, which was loaded from the DB in the start. Isn't that true? If yes, then if some other mechanism can get your data refreshed, then I don't think you would still need to reload your classes. And I actually meant that you should use EhCache or something similar.

Comment: @AdeelAnsari Actually I really do not want to reinvent the wheel if something is already available in the market. So I think I can take a look at EhCache.

Comment: You can but if your requirement is small you can just add Thread which will reduce the application load.

Comment: @SubhrajyotiMajumder: Ehcache is not something heavy, actually they call it lightweight and simple. Take a look, http://ehcache.org/about/features

Comment: thanks for the link Man :). Yap it is light weight but don't you thing for single map data handling and that to one hr interval for data updation requirement, any library would be required?

Comment: If I were you, I wouldn't be using any extra library for that. You can go with Quartz scheduler, as others pointed out. But wait... that's also another library. You can also go by yourself using Timer and TimerTask, otherwise. But you must know what you are doing. I'm not scaring you, it's gonna be simple.

Comment: In the run method add a while loop and load the data and just before the end `Thread#sleep` 1 hour. Ohh one more thing can also add Shutdownhook close it properly. What about this? :)

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use a [Quartz](http://quartz-scheduler.org/) for this purpose.
You simply set up a task for it, and it will take care of the periodical updates for you.
I think, [Tutorial 2](http://quartz-scheduler.org/documentation/quartz-2.x/tutorials/tutorial-lesson-02) is made just for you :D

On the other hand you should handle the paralel access/writing on your configuration Map object - take care of thread safety!

Comment: Yip, the very first code example is made for you. The example builds a Job, a trigger, which fires in every 40 seconds, and schedules the job with the given trigger.